# Updating rCharts nvd3 chart in Shiny dashboard

Tags: shiny, nvd3.js, rcharts

I've built a Shiny dashboard app that shows a number of metrics data of scientific articles by university School. The app is at https://ttso.shinyapps.io/2amconf and the code https://gist.github.com/tts/900b4e27bf37e8969ebd with some sample data of file *dataforcharts.csv* which is the data source of my question here.

My problem is the NVD3 chart on the landing tab.

At first it draws OK the selected max 2 items (=articles) from the chosen School, which is *All* at the beginning. But whenever I select some School - and *selectizeInput* then updates the list of items of that School - nothing happens.

I've tried to debug what's going on.

```
validate(
   need(!is.null(itemsData()), "Please select some items")
)

dataC <- itemsData() 

browser()
```

When the execution stops there, I can see that dataC do contains the chosen data.

Console utput of *options(shiny.trace=TRUE)* is talkative but I cannot really understand what it tries to tell me. Here's a snippet from the last message when the chart ought to render with new data, but does not.

```
SEND {"errors":[],"values":{"chart":"<style>.rChart {width: 800px;
height: 400px} </style>\n<script type='text/javascript'>\n
$(document).ready(function(){\n      drawchart()\n    });\n   
function drawchart(){  \n      var opts = {\n \"dom\":
\"chart\",\n\"width\":    800,\n\"height\":    400,\n\"x\":
\"id\",\n\"y\": \"value\",\n\"group\": \"variable\",\n\"type\":
\"multiBarChart\",\n\"id\": \"chart\" \n},\n        data = 
[ TEXT CUT OFF ] drawchart(){  \n   n       return chart;\n  
});\n    };\n</script>"},"inputMessages":[]}
```

Again, *data=* includes the correct, chosen data.

Is something wrong with my reactive values?

EDIT after observation: if I delete all selected item(s) before switching to another School, this works.

So, after some trial & error, this looks promising:

```
itemsData <- reactive({

  if( is.null(input$items) ){
   return(NULL)
  }

isolate(selectedSchoolData()[selectedSchoolData()$Title %in%
input$items, ])

})
```

but I haven't yet got my head over isolate() so if someone could explain, why this works, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with this.

```
 itemsData <- reactive({

  if( is.null(input$items) ){
   return(NULL)
 }

  isolate(selectedSchoolData()[selectedSchoolData()$Title %in%
   input$items, ])

})
```